# MySQL Query in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, json

This is my actual query in MySQL:

```
 SELECT sndprefix, COUNT(*) FROM `inbox` WHERE
 (
 sndprefix='22' OR 
 sndprefix='23' OR 
 sndprefix='32' OR 
 sndprefix='33' OR 
 sndprefix='34' OR 
 sndprefix='42' OR 
 sndprefix='43'
 ) 
 GROUP BY sndprefix;
```

I'm getting the CORRECT response such as:

```
 sndprefix  COUNT(*)
 22     3
 23     5
 32     1
 33     1
 43     1
```

My question is what is the PHP code to show this query in the browser and to be parsed as json format too.

Thanks in advance.

Apology if I have not posted the code earlier, I was trying to familiarize myself with stackoverlow's UI finding the edit option..

Here's the code I've tried so far:

```
 <?php
 $query="SELECT sndprefix, COUNT(*) FROM `inbox` WHERE
 (
 sndprefix='22' OR 
 sndprefix='23' OR 
 sndprefix='32' OR 
 sndprefix='33' OR 
 sndprefix='34' OR 
 sndprefix='42' OR 
 sndprefix='43'
 ) 
 GROUP BY sndprefix;";

 $result = mysql_query($query);
while($sunget = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    foreach($sunget AS $key => $value) { $conget[$key] = stripslashes($value); }
 echo "". nl2br( $sunget['sndprefix']) ."";
 }
 ?>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Use [this](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_intro.asp) tutorial. Then use the function `json_encode()` to convert the array you get to JSON.

Comment: not question-related, but wouldn't it be better if you used `sndprefix IN ('22','23','32','33','34','42','43')`?

Comment: @JohnSantos, you have got to be kidding. stackoverflow.com is not a "please code this for me" service... you need to show that you have tried something. Google turns up lots of results for "php mysql query" and "php json".

Comment: @Hassan Don't **ever** direct people to that site. This is especially the case for that idiotic mysql "tutorial". They are suggesting you make your aplpication vulnerable to SQL injection at best.

Comment: @RepWhoringPeeHaa Haha I wan't aware you had such strong feelings about it. But it's a very simple "starting point". But I think it would be foolish to *only* use it without covering some security holes.

Comment: @Hassan First starters `mysql_*` will [be deprecated](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php) and here is just a [huge security hole](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp) without any mention about it. Hence: don't direct people to that site for the better of the web.

Comment: @RepWhoringPeeHaa I think you're exaggerating. A simple first introduction to a topic shouldn't have to cover all the security threats possible.

Comment: @Hassan , there is difference between "all security threats" and "basics". In that example escaping `$_POST` values would be "basics".

Comment: This isn't about covering all possible security threats. This is **mandatory**. Anybody who has the slightest idea what he is doing in php and mysql should know this. I will go as far as saying if you don't know this you are not allowed to do anything with a database.

Comment: @Hassan Can we please stop pretending that people who need *"A simple first introduction to a topic"* don't immediately copy/paste that code onto a production site. No, I disagree: topical introductions should go out of their way to cover the major security holes.

Comment: @nadirs Thanks for your suggestion. i'm new with mysql. Yes the query is pretty much inexpensive compared to using OR i'll try to use it instead.

Comment: @rdlowrey Those tutorials would be much less accessible to early beginners. And if someone wants to copy-paste that code to a production application, then they're just being stupid. That doesn't mean the tutorials shouldn't exist.

Comment: @RepWhoringPeeHaa Yes, that particular tutorial is not particularly great, but to say the *entire site* shouldn't be used is an overstatement.

Comment: @Hassan The reason I say that is because the site is [a bad resource in general](http://w3fools.com/). It's just that on that mysql tutorial they tend to give away other peoples personal information through leaks.

Comment: @tereško I'm new in php but I'm not a vampire. If you feel like not helping it's okay. =)

Comment: +1 for the baptism of fire you're getting here, and for improving your question!

Comment: @halfer haha i didn't expect people to have irrelevant arguments. it so happens security is a broad topic and individuals have different opinions.

Comment: @JohnSantos really people don't have different opinions. It's just that there are people who know what they are doing and people who don't. And that's ok. But don't mind me trying to educate people :)

Comment: @SeanOwen , why did you close-vote the question after it was updated ?

Comment: @JohnSantos Congratulations on a reopened question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well .. looks like question got updated.

You are doing it wrong .. at multiple levels. I guess bad tutorials are at fault.

- **The query**

  You should read more about `WHERE` clause, and how to use it. [This page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/range-optimization.html) will give some basic info, but you should find some book about MySQL (and only about MySQL, no PHP included).

  This would make the query much easier to read:

  ```
  SELECT 
      sndprefix AS prefix, 
      COUNT(*) AS count 
  FROM inbox 
  WHERE sndprefix IN ('22', '23', '32', '33', '34', '42', '43') 
  GROUP BY sndprefix;
  ```

  Also, you might want to learn about [JOIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/range-optimization.html) statements in MySQL, because I get a feeling, that this list of specific prefixes has something in common.

  And since the prefixes are repeating, they might be better off in a separate table. At least from [normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form) point of view.
- **Querying database in PHP**

  You should not writing new code with the ancient `mysql_*` functions. They are no longer maintained and community has begun the [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799), and now there is even has been a warning added in manual: (see the [red box](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)) .

  Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you cannot decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you care to learn, [here is a quite good PDO-related tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

  Lets assume that you have use PDO to interact with database (I just prefer it over MySQLi).

  ```
  $connection = new PDO(
                    'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=my_magc_db;charset=UTF-8', 
                    'username', 'password');
  $connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
  $connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
  // the connection has been established, and object configured

  $sql = 'SELECT 
              sndprefix AS prefix, 
              COUNT(*) AS count 
          FROM inbox 
          WHERE sndprefix IN ('22', '23', '32', '33', '34', '42', '43') 
          GROUP BY sndprefix';

  $statement = $connection->query( $sql );
  // no need to prepare the statement this time, because values are predefined
  // if values '22', '23', etc. depend on user input, code would be different

  $data = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  // now $data contains all the values.
  // you van use var_dump($data) to "look inside" variable
  ```
- **making JSON**

  Since `$data` already is an array with all the values, you can simply write this 
  [`echo json_encode( $data );`](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) to generate JSON.
- **making output**

  Since you have already the array, you can just write:

  ```
  foreach ( $data as $row ) {
      echo $row['prefix'], ' ', $row['count'], PHP_EOL, '<br>';
  }
  ```

  Any questions ?